# What is the name of this modal interface element?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm not sure what the name of this Mac OS X Cocoa user interface element is (the modal container that up in a window). Thanks!

[image: What is this?]

Comment: @Jason, that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm too tired to give a full answer with links and the actual class name, so the comment will give enough for Kevin to find it with some effort, but will leave the question open in case somebody wants to write a full answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [sheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-CJECBHJE), otherwise known as a document-modal dialog. You can show them using the [`NSPanel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPanel) class.

Comment: Thanks John! I felt like a fool for not being able to find the name by  Google! Cheers!

Comment: @Kevin Sylvestre: don't feel stupid at all, those kinds of little vocabulary tweaks are really difficult to search on and are what make going from one environment to the next so difficult :)